# Loading tweet json file with multiple json objects into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, twitter, nested

I have a JSON file (`tweetObject.json`) including ~600 lines where each line is a response from the Twitter API, which contains 100 tweets or so along with their metadata.

**My Questions:**

1. How to extract specific tweet attributes, e.g., `username` from my JSON file? (I was thinking about loading the JSON into pandas dataframe where each column stores only one attribute/field and then select the specific attribute I need. But I'm open to any other solution as well.
2. How to load the JSON file into a pandas dataframe? I used `json.load`, but I got the `JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 173419)`. After some research, I found the reason for this error is probably because `json.load` does not decode multiple JSON objects.
3. I also have a flatten version of my JSON file which keeps 1 tweet per line. I also tried the `json.load` with this file, but still, get the same error.

Here is my code to load the json:

```
with open('tweetObject_v2.json') as json_file:
    data_list = json.load(json_file)
```

Sorry I didn't write the sample of the tweet object JSON because even one line of this file was too long. But you can find a sample Twitter API (v2) response here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/example-payloads

Comment: added a couple dataframe extraction examples to my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you can read each line of the flattened file and then load into json, you can do this:

```
data = example line above in your questions
dataj = json.loads(data)
dataj['author']['username']
```

Output

```
'Megresistor'
```

If you are able to get a dataframe built, and the dataframe has the user column (which should be a dictionary), you can use this to pull out the screen_name

```
df.user.str.get('screen_name')
```

and this gets the FIRST screen name of a user mention. User mentions is a list so this is taking the first element of the list. It's a bit more complicated to get all when there's a list but at least you can a feel of how to navigate the dataframe.

```
df.entities.str.get('user_mentions').str[0].str.get('screen_name')
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your answer.. Did you mean loading the data in json file line by line?? I just posted my updated code in my question.

Comment: yes, if you were able to reach each line and loop through you can parse out the usernames into a list. it's not clear what your data looks like so it's tough to give you more detailed answer. it's not a way to get it into pandas. because twitter responses are pretty complex, i write my parsing scripts for specific actions. you might want to try flatten_json instead of json_normalize. i've used it with other complex json structures.

Comment: can you post a link to the text file(s)?

Comment: Thank you Johnathan for your updates. I actually figured it out. I read each line and loop through lines (I loaded each line and put it in an array). Then, I converted the array to a pandas dataframe, and finally, I used `json_normalize` on the resulting dataframe. When I checked the columns, I found some columns include an array or object. So, I decided to repeat the same steps with the flatten_json file. Fortunately, this gave me a dataframe with a separate column for each attribute (including username :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally figured it out. Hope it helps others with similar questions

#### Answer to question 2: How to load a json file with multiple json objects into pandas dataframe?

Since `json.loads` doesn't decode multiple JSON object, I loop through lines and loaded line by line, and stored the results in an array. Next, I converted the array to a pandas dataframe:

```
tweets = []
for line in open('tweetsFlatten.json', 'r'):
     tweets.append(json.loads(line))

df1 = pd.DataFrame(tweets)
```

Checking columns of df1, I found that some columns contain arrays or objects (i.e., there was no separate column for each attribute). For example, the column `author` keeps the author object which included id (user id), username, etc.

#### Answer to question 1: How to extract/access specific tweet attributes in a tweet JSON file?

In order to be able to access specific attributes (e.g., `username`), I used `json_normalize`:

```
df_new = json_normalize(tweets)  
df_new.columns  
#df_new is a new df where each arrtibute has a separate column. 
#For example, instead of an `author` column which kept various attributes (id, username, etc.), the new dataframe has separate columns for each of them (e.g., `author.id`, `author.username`, etc.

df_new['author.username'].head()
```

**NOTES:**

- I used the Twitter API V2, so the response JSON file was in [version 2 format](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet).
- I used the flatten version of the json file, because I found it easier to work with (e.g., to access specific attributes)